# How to animate swapping of two different sized widge in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I need to swap two text widgets of different sizes in flutter. I'm trying to swap the two text when user taps on the second text. I tried animatedPositioned but it looks weird because the sizes were different. Note that the text needs to change size as well.

For reference, I've attached the gif.

```dart
class SwapWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 80,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: const [
                    Text(
                      "\$",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 40,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "400",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 80,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        height: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              Text(
                '2345',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
              Icon(Icons.swap_vert),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[Animation gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mbZf.gif)

Comment: Animation gif link isnt working for me, you can follow below post also we have `DefaultAnimatedText` this may help

Comment: @YeasinSheikh There was some issue with the earlier link. I've updated the gif link.

Answer (score 0):

for switching Widgets you can use the AnimatedSwitcher.
See: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html

Standard behaviour is fading in and out. But if you use a ScaleTransition in the transitionBuilder argument of AnimatedSwitcher it would scale the first down and the second widget is growing in.
In every case, AnimatedWitcher works with swapping widgets of different sizes.

Comment: AnimatedSwitcher works fine if we want to switch one widget into another but in my case, there are two different text widgets which are swapping their position as well as textstyles.

Comment: Ok, yeah I already noticed that I might have mixed "swapping" with "switching" and misinterpreted your issue.